# JS append params with %20 changed auto to space

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

Hi evry one i'm using backoneJs and coffeeScript and trying to pass an encoded params but in browser it's change '%20' to spaces In FireFox(encodeURIComponent) :

```
 type = "two words"
 path ='/page1?type='+encodeURIComponent type
 backbone.history.navigate path, trigger: false
```

> return :  www.website.com/page1?type=two words
>
> I want it to be : www.website.com/page1?type=two%20words

any idea please :)

Comment: that's what you see in browser, but it's actually `%20`. Also, the code should be more of a working snippet, should not contain `SyntaxErrors`

Comment: @DavidThomas I'm using CoffeeScript encodeURIComponent(type) <==> encodeURIComponent type

Comment: @DavidThomas the OP is working with **CoffeeScript**, thus his syntax is correct.

Comment: @coding_idiot this code work on chrome and not on firefox

Comment: Where exactly are you see the space when you expect a `%20`? In the console? The debugger? The browser's URL bar?

Comment: in browser's URL bar (newest  FireFox), it's working in console, debugger, chrome, safari but not in firefox i guess it's rewriting urls and replace every '%20' with spaces bu if i encode a string with '/' like two/words it write two%2Fwords

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your code looks ok, if you use the `encodeURIComponent` function it will turn all the spaces into `%20`, like this:

```
var foo= "hello world";
encodeURIComponent foo
> "hello%20world"
```

So in your code the `encodeURIComponent` will replace the space as well:

```
type = "two words"
path ='/page1?type='+encodeURIComponent type
// "/page1?type=two%20words"

backbone.history.navigate path, trigger: false
```

If you are experiencing some error then it's not because of this snippet, it's something that happens in another part of your code.

### By the way,

if you are experiencing some problems with the `encodeURIComponent` function **you can always use the `.replace()` method to force the replacement of spaces**, like this:

```
type = "two words"
path ='/page1?type='+(encodeURIComponent type).replace(new RegExp(" ", "g"), "%20")
// "/page1?type=two%20words"                   ^ here you force the replacement of spaces
```

Comment: No sir this code work good in chrome and safari and not the newset version of firefox !!!

Comment: thnks sir for your response i have this pb only in firefox i had to replace every space with '+' to avoid spaces in url

Comment: @nasser if my answer solved your question, consider marking it as correct to make it easier for people (with the same trouble) to find it. By the way, you're welcome.

Comment: No sir it does not solve my issue if you have firefox try an url containig  %20 and you will see

Comment: I don't know watcha say then... your problem is related to something else than this snippet